# Is it possble to do comparion of two variables in javascript of different types

Tags: javascript

I am having a jstree and in javascript function i am checking which node has been selected thats working fine. But when i assign that node value to a variable then do comparasion with a normal string variable thats not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bdeViewNew').on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
        var i, j, r = [];

        for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {


            var x = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text;


            r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);


            if(x=="Hadoop") 
                {alert("hi");}
            else{
                alert("hello");
            }


        }
    });

});
```

any one know how we can do such comparasion?

thanks in advance

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Please get at least the tags right. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"not working"*..? what is happening..? any alerts/errors..?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your variable has some unexpected whitespace at the start or the end, that's a common problem. You should be able to get rid of it with

```
var x = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim();
```

Should work on all modern browsers.

Also keep in mind that JavaScript has function scope, not block scope like you might be used to from C/C++ or Java. The x you declare there is visible throughout the function, not just in the for loop. You should probably declare it at the same time as i, j and r.